# Bulk Insert is throwing an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, load, bulkinsert

I have a source file with ".dat" extension  and want to load it into as table in SSMS. My Code below is here:

But is gives me the following error. I also opened the file in Notepad++ to check the ROWTERMINATOR, which appeared to be LF.

**Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 34
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 25. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 34
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".**

Code:

```
USE myDB
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable]

(
Column1 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column2 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column3 NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
Column4 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column5 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column6 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column7  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column8  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column9  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column10  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column11  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column12 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column13  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column14 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column15  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column16 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column17  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column18  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column19  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column20  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column21  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column22 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column23 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column24 NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
Column25 NVARCHAR(255) NULL
);

BULK 
INSERT [dbo].[myTable]
FROM 'C:\Users\John\Documents\work\MyFile.dat'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myTable]
```

Below is the sample of the data and that very row that SSMS is failing:

`Kansas City    1   494124  20  McDonalds KANSAS CUSTOMERS  22  WYANDOTTE COUNTY    239 Wyandotte County    964 S 73RD ST       KANSAS CITY                 KS  66111   2805    Y   Y   Y   N   N   4   D   Old School Loyal    N   49412401`

Comment: Appears to be??? Can you not confirm line ending chars? It might be cr-lf. (\r\n)

Comment: Yes, the rowterminator is LF which is '\n' , but i did try '\r\n' as  well

Comment: Sample lines from data? How many columns in your data? Is it more or less than 9?

Comment: it's 25 columns. But I cannot reveal it for security reason. But it does insert  a number of rows but all in one (25th) column from the source file when I comment out FIRSTROW AND ROWTERMINATOR

Comment: Well without sample data can't help much. You should look at data though. It says it's failing on column 9. You have 9 columns in your table but you're trying to import 25 fields??? That's a problem.

Comment: No, I do have 25 columns in my table definition. He it's just a representation. And the 9 the columns in the code above represents the failing 25th column in my actual code which I cannot reveal.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem where I work. If you have line feed endings, and, logically use `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'`, bcp adds `\r` to it:

> When you use bcp interactively and specify \n (newline) as the row
>   terminator, bcp automatically prefixes it with a \r (carriage return)
>   character, which results in a row terminator of \r\n.
>   ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx))

I'm not sure it helps in your case, but if I use `ROWTERMINATOR = "0x0a"` it works perfectly fine.

**Edit**

In your comment you say you are trying to insert 25 columns into a 9 column table. Obviously that's not going to work. You should fix the number of columns first.

Comment: No, I do have 25 columns in my table definition. He it's just a representation. And the 9 the columns in the code above represents the failing 25th column in my actual code which I cannot reveal.

Comment: Also I'm not using bcp utility

Comment: I've modified the actual code which is failing. Please take a look at the updated code.

Comment: I've also added a data sample

Comment: @enigma6205, I can't see anything obvious wrong with it. Do you create the file yourself? If so, you can try changing the field terminators.

Comment: @enigma6205, Also, is it correct everything is an `nvarchar`? There are numbers in your datasample. Make sure you choose the correct datatype.

Comment: Hi  HoneyBadger, I'm not creating it myself. I'm receiving it that way.

Comment: Your sample is difficult to check, since I can't tell the difference between a space and a tab.

Comment: Does the error also occur if you remove all but the first row?

Comment: As I said earlier I've oped the source file in Notepad ++ which clearly shows LF as delimiter. But you are correct, there are spaces as well, but within a column.

Answer (score 0):

be sure your user database authentication have access to bulk insert?
If a user uses a SQL Server login, the security profile of the SQL Server process account is used. A login using SQL Server authentication cannot be authenticated outside of the Database Engine. Therefore, when a BULK INSERT command is initiated by a login using SQL Server authentication, the connection to the data is made using the security context of the SQL Server process account (the account used by the SQL Server Database Engine service).
To successfully read the source data you must grant the account used by the SQL Server Database Engine, access to the source data. In contrast, if a SQL Server user logs on by using Windows Authentication, the user can read only those files that can be accessed by the user account, regardless of the security profile of the SQL Server process.

For example, consider a user who logged in to an instance of SQL Server by using Windows Authentication. For the user to be able to use BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET to import data from a data file into a SQL Server table, the user account requires read access to the data file. With access to the data file, the user can import data from the file into a table even if the SQL Server process does not have permission to access the file. The user does not have to grant file-access permission to the SQL Server process.

if you have access to bulk insert to database 
check your datatype and datalen in your dat file

Comment: I'm using windows Authentication and I have admin. I have  access to the file as to bulk insert on my server. I'checked data length in the source file and it matches columns datatypes

Comment: "IMPORTANT!  ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). You should **NOT** change `nvarchar` to `ntext`.

Comment: HoneyBadger, I absolutely agree with you. Thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

`ROWTERMINATOR = "0x0a"`

For the win!